# Issues with retrieving data from xml

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm trying to retrieve the subscriber count from this xml file but I'm having an issue getting the data. Currently I'm using doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode for each level but I'm not having much luck and as I'm not very familiar with C# xml I dont really know what my issue is. Any help would be much appreciated and the xml is attached below.

I am trying to get the data from the subscriberCount and my current code is attatched at the bottom, although it doesn't work

-Max

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
   <kind>youtube#channelListResponse</kind>
   <etag>"xxx"</etag>
   <pageInfo>
      <totalResults>1</totalResults>
      <resultsPerPage>1</resultsPerPage>
   </pageInfo>
   <items>
      <kind>youtube#channel</kind>
      <etag>"xxx"</etag>
      <id>xxx</id>
      <statistics>
         <viewCount>0</viewCount>
         <commentCount>0</commentCount>
         <subscriberCount>200</subscriberCount>
         <hiddenSubscriberCount>false</hiddenSubscriberCount>
         <videoCount>5</videoCount>
      </statistics>
   </items>
</Root>


string totalSubs = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("Root").SelectSingleNode("items").SelectSingleNode("statistics").SelectSingleNode("subscriberCount").Value;
```

Comment: SelectSingleNode uses xpath so select a specific node, if you are using it to loop all nodes, you are using it wrong.  There is a ChildNodes property that you can loop/iterate instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement root = doc.Root;

            Response response = new Response();
            response.kind = (string)root.Element("kind");
            response.etag = (string)root.Element("etag");
            response.totalResults  = (int)root.Descendants("totalResults").FirstOrDefault();
            response.resultsPerPage = (int)root.Descendants("resultsPerPage").FirstOrDefault();

            XElement items = root.Element("items");
            response.itemKind = (string)items.Element("kind");
            response.itemEtag = (string)items.Element("etag");
            response.id = (string)items.Element("id");

            XElement statistics = items.Element("statistics");
            response.viewCount = (int)statistics.Element("viewCount");
            response.commentCount = (int)statistics.Element("commentCount");
            response.subscriberCount = (int)statistics.Element("subscriberCount");
            response.hiddenSubscriberCount = (Boolean)statistics.Element("hiddenSubscriberCount");
            response.videoCount = (int)statistics.Element("videoCount");
        }
    }
    public class Response
    {
        public string kind { get; set; }
        public string etag { get; set; }
        public int totalResults { get; set; }
        public int resultsPerPage { get; set; }

        public string itemKind { get; set; }
        public string itemEtag { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int viewCount { get; set; }
        public int commentCount { get; set; }
        public int subscriberCount { get; set; }
        public Boolean hiddenSubscriberCount { get; set; }
        public int videoCount { get; set; }

    }
}
```